# Is establish_connection on worker boot still required on Rails 6 and Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma, ruby-on-rails-6

I read on Heroku that for Rails (4+ they say) I should add the following directive to Puma, when I use multiple workers and I preload the app:

```
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

However I have both `preload_app!` and multiple `workers` without that code... and the app seems to work fine.

Am I missing something? Is that still required? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `establish_connection` call is no longer needed, assuming you're running Rails 5.2+.

The config code for the Puma-maintained plugin for best practices Puma configuration on Heroku (it lives [here](https://github.com/puma/puma-heroku)) currently includes the following:

```rb
# Not necessary in Rails 5.2+, see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29807
if defined?(::ActiveRecord) && defined?(::ActiveRecord::Base) && Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) < Gem::Version.new('5.2.0')
    c.before_fork { ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! }
    c.on_worker_boot { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
end
```

Note the comment here. A little more digging on the linked PR and some PRs it linked me to led to the PR that actually removes the need for this stuff: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31241. In this PR, the question is explicitly asked,

> Does this mean that if we have existing before_fork and on_worker_boot blocks in our pre-Rails 5.2.0 puma.rb file, we can now simply remove those blocks after upgrading to Rails 5.2.0?

And the answer, my friend, is...

> Yes. (Assuming they're doing AR connection management, of course.)
> They're perfectly safe to leave there, so it's not called out in the upgrade guide, but they should no longer be necessary.